# Toggle visibility of an html table with master child details

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the an html table which shows master-child details. 
On clicking the plus symbol (+) against the master record, corresponding child details to be shown. I have the test setup here http://jsfiddle.net/BEEU3/3/. (which is not perfect)
I know how to traverse the dom to get the child elements but please suggest a solution which yields **best performance**.

HTML:

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
<tr>
 <th></th>
 <th>Name</th>
 <th>Details</th>
</tr>
    <tr>
        <td><i class="icon-plus-sign"></i></td>
        <td>name1</td>
        <td>detail1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="tr-child">
        <td colspan="3">
            <table class="table table-bordered">
                <tr>
                    <th>SubDetails</th>
                    <th>SubDetails</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>SD1</td>
                    <td>Test1</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

jQuery:

```
$(".icon-plus-sign").click(function () {
      $('.tr-child').toggle("slow");
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `closest()` and `next()` methods. At first `closest()` finds the closest tr parent of the clicked element, then `next()` selects the next sibling of the tr element which is an element with class of `.tr-child`.

```
$(".icon-plus-sign").click(function () {
     $(this).closest('tr').next().toggle("slow");
});
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BEEU3/6/)**

- **[closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)**
- **[next()](http://api.jquery.com/next/)**